# Onesignar get tags from notification android?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

Iam using  rest api of Onesignar to send notification to android devices , i wana send addition data to user like this

```
{"user_level","10"}
```

Iam using tags but i cannot retrive this tag by using function

```
 OneSignal.getTags(new OneSignal.GetTagsHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void tagsAvailable(JSONObject tags) {
                        Log.d("debug_Tag", tags.toString());
                    }
                });
```

it always return empty object  . How i can retrive tag from notification or set addition data to notification with Onesignar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data with the notification you will need to set the `data` field on the OneSignal [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call.

```
{
  "app_id": "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
  "included_segments": ["All"],
  "data": {"user_level","10"},
  "contents": {"en": "English Message"}
}
```

Or the "Additional Data" field under Options on the "New Message" page on the OneSignal dashboard.

You can then call `setNotificationOpenedHandler` in your app's code to add `NotificationOpenedHandler` to your app the will fire `notificationOpened`.

```
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
        .init();
   }

  // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is running.
  private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements NotificationOpenedHandler {
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
      try {
        if (additionalData != null) {
          Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Full additionalData:\n" + additionalData.toString());
        }
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

`additionalData` will contain the what you set on the `data` field when you create the notification.

`OneSignal.getTags` only gets tag values you set on the user with `OneSiganal.sendTags`.

Comment: Thank u xD .Onesignar is very simple to use